# Error passing C array as char* function parameter

Tags: c, arrays, function, char

I'm trying to make a simple code in c language (Stupid question, but I'm learning), I dont  understand that this code gives me an error ... I must be doing wrong, I can not know that I have to change...sorry for my English ... thanks in advance to all

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* to_up(char* str_); 

int main()
{
    char any_phrase[] = "This is a phrase";
    printf("%s\n", to_up(any_phrase));
    printf("%s\n", to_up("this is another phrase"));
    return 0;
}

char* to_up(char* str_) 
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; str_[i]; i++) 
        str_[i] = toupper(str_[i]);
    return str_;
}
```

Comment: `toupper()` needs to be passed an unsigned char (implicitly converted to int) or EOF. You should write it like `toupper((unsigned char)str_[i])`. Problem can show up if you get a phrase like "¿Cómo te llamas?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that when you pass the string as "this is another phrase" on its own, as in not contained in a variable, the string is what's known as a string literal.  What this means, among other things, is that the string is constant: you simply are not allowed to modify.

To solve your problem you'd have to store the string in a variable so it is allowed to be modified by your to_up() function call since it modifies the contents of the string.

Answer (score 2):

A string literal is usually in read-only memory.  As far as the standard is concerned, trying to modify it will result in undefined behaviour regardless of where it is in memory.  There have been *many* questions asked about this problem already.

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
printf("%s\n", to_up("this is another phrase"));
```

You are trying to modify a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles OK for me, but gives a bus error (core dump) at runtime.

The trouble is that a string literal can be stored in read-only memory, so you can't modify the literal string as your code does.  With enough compiler warnings enabled, your compiler will warn you (GCC requires `-Wwrite-strings` - at least, in GCC 4.4 and above).